# Best approach for names input

Tags: django

I am making a little website with python/django for publication handling where an author can upload a paper. The website is only used by a small group of institute members (around 100 people).

So there is a field for co-authors. Most of the time all the co-authors are the institute members, but sometimes they are also not from the institute (so they don't have a UserProfile in the system).

I need to make co-author input field user friendly, so there should be some kind of autocomplete when you start typing the name of a person. And a person mentioned in the co-authors field should receive an automated message, saying a new publication was added for them.

What would be the best approach to make such a field? If I make it just a text field and after parse a string to search for people names there is a always a chance for people named the same.

Comment: What information can you all collect about the co-authors? Do you only get the name?

Comment: No, all user profiles have e-mail, phone, room number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's always some chance that two people have the same name. You could guard against it by displaying additional information about them (e.g. department affiliation), so that even among similar or identical names, people can choose the right person.

But obviously you cannot expect uploaders to know or search for the institute-internal ID of their co-authors, so there's no getting around selecting the co-authors by name.

So I would just set up autocompletion based on the names in the system, while presumably allowing for external authors as well who don't have an institute profile. You may or may not want to prompt for additional information (e.g. organization affiliation) of new external co-authors so you can create a profile for them.

Comment: I could add additional information like department to autocomplete, but the problem is: I only need to have people initials in that co-author field. So how could I make that the additional information also gets returned to website's logic?

Comment: Obviously you will have to create separate fields for any information you need and save the submitted fields as appropriate. There's a conflict between a) requiring only minimal data and b) uniquely identifying persons so you can notify them of their inclusion in a paper. You may want to ask if b) is worth the trouble or if maybe it would be sufficient to provide submitters with an e-mail field so you can send notifications about the submission to the specified email adresses.

Comment: If your question refers to how to display department or other information on autocomplete without then including these information in the co-author field while at the same time using them internally for identification, this should be possible by switching between a select field (which could point to identically named but separate individuals, whose secondary identifying characteristics like department affiliation could be displayed in a read-only label) and a free-form field for entering external authors.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer! That's exactly to what I was referring. I was thinking of making the fields for internal and externals authors separate, but the thing is that most of the authors don't want to bother with it since mostly they just copy/paste the co-authors list from other resources. So I was thinking of some elegant way to avoid it :)